# selecting unique table on each condition with mysql

Tags: mysql

hello everyone and thx to your real hard work on spreading knowledge. 
the problem that I'm facing is that i don't know how to select from different tables in just a single query.
 for example:

```
select * 
from google if('some condition is true')
OR

from yahoo if('other condition is true')
```

Comment: What if both conditions are true, or both conditions are false?

Comment: here I only have only one condition true because i only have 6 different type to chose one from each time.

Comment: In that case, the second test is redundant.

Comment: the OR that i use is not logical. i just wanted to show different conditions that I have. that's why I didn't include it in my code section at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement

```
IF ('some condition is true') THEN
   SELECT * FROM google;
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM yahoo;
END IF;
```